# How do I change this JavaScript to use arrow functions in order to access a property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I believe this can be solved using an arrow-function, but I'm not sure how. I would like to access `this.props` inside of the `render` Function. I know I could pass it over as an argument, but would rather not. Is this possible using arrow functions? If so, what do I need to change?

```
class View {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options;
  }
  render(el, props = {}) {
    this.props = props;
    el.innerHTML = this.options.render(el);
  }
} 

var Test = new View({
  render() {
    return `${this.props.test}`
    //
    // Also, tried ${props.test} in my template literal
    //
  }
});

Test.render(document.getElementById("main"), {
    test:"123"
})
```

Comment: No, this is exactly *not* possible using arrow functions. You are looking for `this.options.render.call(this, el)`.

Comment: Related: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions allow you to access the this of the external closure, not of the calling function space. A defining point of functions is to isolate it from the callee's variables. Arrow functions simply make the context, or the `this` object, to be equal of it's definition closure. Thus

```
var that = this;
(() => console.log(that === this))();
```

Will print true, while

```
var that = this;
(function(){console.log(that === this)})();
```

Will print false
The reason that the arrow's function can access the `this` context, is because its defined there, not because it's called there.

The only way to force the context object is by using `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.apply`

Comment: You rock! `this.options.render.call(this, el) does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the `this.props = props` allocation? You could have something like this.

```js
class View {
  
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options;
  }

  render(el, props = {}) {
    el.innerHTML = this.options.render(props);
  }
}

var test = new View({ render: x => `${x.test}` });

test.render(document.getElementById("main"), { test:"123" });
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```